# Hibernate returning empty list even though the values are available in the table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I looked various solutions posted here but nothing worked.

**Controller**

```
List<Company> empIds = empDao.findempbyId(Id,branch);
logger.info("Emp List:"+empIds );
```

**Dao Layer**

```
private static final String FIND_EMPLOYEES = "select EMP_ID from myschema.emp where id = :Id and branch = :branch";

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<Company> findempbyId(String Id, String branch) {        
    return getSession().createSQLQuery(FIND_EMPLOYEES)
            .setParameter("Id", Id)
            .setParameter("branch", branch)
            .list();
}
```

**Output**

```
Emplist : []
```

Comment: Do you really need to have myschema in query? did you try without myschema.?

Comment: The other queries in the same dao class is working fine. Myschema is required Nambari.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "select EMP_ID from myschema.emp where EMP_ID.id = :Id ;)
    .addEntity(Employee.class)
    .setParameter("Id", "72");
    .setParameter("branch", "branch");
    List result = query.list();
```